# Expected value of a card game, with a fixed probability of playing it again.

Tags: probability

A person has to select one of three cards. One card would get him a 
reward of 1 dollar. Another one would not give him any return. The 
third one would give him a return of 2 dollars and also compels him 
to select one of the 3 cards once again- all similar to the first set 
of 3 cards. The person has no way of identifying the cards beforehand 
and is equally likely to take any of the 3 cards at any stage. Find 
the expected value.

Comment: You need to give these questions more descriptive titles. This is your earlier title with an underscore added (and that was not an apt title either).

Comment: @EricTressler - Sorry. Will do so in near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we had only the first two cards, the expected value would be
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{2}(1) + \frac{1}{2}(0) = 0.5$$
With the third card, it becomes:
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{3}(1) + \frac{1}{3}(0) + \frac{1}{3}\left(2 + E[X]\right).$$
Writing it like this allows you to avoid the geometric series that is lurking behind that third card -- provided that you know $E[X]$ exists. In this case it does, but if $E[X] = \infty$, this is invalid, and you need to expand this into a geometric series.

**Edit:** I fixed this, I was previously treating it as though the first card were worth 1 dollar, the second card 2 dollars, and the third worth a chance to pick another card, and to play again as well.

Comment: I think it should be E[X] = 1/3(1) + 1/3(0) + 1/3(2 + E[X]). This will give E[X] = 3/2.

Comment: You are correct, I thought he also got to choose one of the two other cards first, for some reason.